# Invoke RESTFul API using WSO2 ESB error

Tags: api, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to invoke a simple RESTFul API that POST username and password  using WSO2 ESB, but i did not get response when trying to invoke it using postman:

the RESTFul API URL is: `http://{REST service IP:port}/api/signup`

the URL to call from ESB is `http://{ESP IP:PORT}/api1/signup`

the API Configuration i made in the WSO2 ESB is

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API_TEST"   context="/api1">
  <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/signup">
    <inSequence>
      <log/>
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address uri="http://< REST service IP:port>/api/signup"/>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <log/>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

I posted a Simple JSON elements:

```
{
  "name":"adnan",
  "password":"adnan1"
}
```

the WSO2 Console show the following message:

> INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:8073ca47-1ea3-4232-bcb7-4f947bca6591, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error while building message, Envelope:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it : I edit the URI-Mapping tp "/" and edit the LOG mediators..

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API_TEST"context="/api1">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/">
  <inSequence>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://{ESB IP:PORT}/api/signup"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
         <send/>
       </outSequence>
   </resource>
  </api>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending json in post body you need to set Content-Type: application/json header from your client.

Comment: Dear ajanthan, I already added this in the client request, I want to check the API XML scripts validity and if there is any success example to invoke external RESTFul web services through WSO2ESB.Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

adding previous answer -: 
for `GET` request this works fine.but `POST` request you need to specify Content-Type:application/json header for the rest client.

Comment: I am add the content type as you can see:     POST /api/signup HTTP/1.1
Host:{ESB-IP and Port}
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 92f70c35-b197-fb34-c70f-3e8ab2aaf300

{
    "name":"adnan",
    "password":"adnan1"
    
    
}